# Doctype and CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a strange issue with doctype declaration. I want my footer to be sticking to the bottom of the page. Its not happening when i declare the doctype. When i remove the doctype, footer sticks to the bottom.

Code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>   
<body>  
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS -

```
#wrapper{
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
min-height:100%;
}

#header{
height: 100px; 
background: green;              
}

#content{
height: 100px; 
background: red; 
width: 400px;
margin:0 auto;      
}

#footer{
height: 50px; 
background: blue;
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396681/why-does-adding-a-doctype-affect-my-css?rq=1

Comment: If you are using XHTML, Use xml:lang and xmlns attributes for your html tag. also close the meta tag with />, also close the html tag with </html>. Also validate your code first. Also state on which browser you are testing it. Also maybe make a jsfiddle. Also 2 side by side pics to show the difference.

Comment: I believe that the doctype is likely telling the browser to enable a default user-agent stylesheet that is adding a margin property to the `<body>` tag. Try adding `margin: 0;` to the body.

Answer (score 0):

An XHTML transitional DOCTYPE does not trigger **quirks mode** in web browsers, but you forgot to add the XHTML namespace, which is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. By doing so, browsers interpret your document as if it was written in legacy markup. The namespace in non-validating user agents is the only way to recognize elements and assign them default styles. If you create an XML document and use the XHTML namespace together with XHTML element mixed up with custom elements, you'll see that only elements which belong to the given XHTML namespace get their default styles from the default browser's stylesheet.

Comment: Declaring the namespace has no effect when the document is served as text/html